# No se genera la matriz en el textArea y me da error cuando doy generar?

Tags: java, matrices, interfaz-gráfica, excepciones, matriz

Cuando pongo generar me salta un error que me dice q esta vacías pero yo ya mando llenando la matriz.
Pero tengo un método donde yo ya mando llenando la matriz y no se como no se aparece
y tengo otro método donde tengo mostrar y generar la matriz.----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

````
 ```  import java.awt.BorderLayout;
    import java.awt.EventQueue;
    
    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    import javax.swing.JPanel;
    import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
    import javax.swing.JLabel;
    import javax.swing.JTextField;
    import javax.swing.JTextPane;
    import javax.swing.JTextArea;
    import javax.swing.JButton;
    import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
    import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
    
    public class EjemploMatriz extends JFrame {
    
        private JPanel contentPane;
        private JTextField textfila;
        private JTextField textColumna;
        private JTextArea textAreaMatriz;
         int mat[][];
        private int f1,c1;
    
        /**
         * Launch the application.
         */
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        EjemploMatriz frame = new EjemploMatriz();
                        frame.setVisible(true);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    
        public void mostrar(int n,int m, int mat[][]) {
            for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {
                for(int j=0;j<m;j++) {
                textAreaMatriz.append(Integer.toString(mat[i][j])+" ");
                    
                }
                textAreaMatriz.append("\n");
                
            }
        }
        
        public void generarM(int n ,int m,int mat[][]) {
            for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {
                for(int j=0;j<m;j++) {
                    mat[i][j]=(int)(Math.random()*10);
                }
            }
            
        }
        
        /**
         * Create the frame.
         */
        public EjemploMatriz() {
            setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            setBounds(100, 100, 517, 423);
            contentPane = new JPanel();
            contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
            setContentPane(contentPane);
            contentPane.setLayout(null);
            
            JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("Fila");
            lblNewLabel.setBounds(95, 90, 45, 13);
            contentPane.add(lblNewLabel);
            
            JLabel lblColumna = new JLabel("Columna");
            lblColumna.setBounds(95, 127, 45, 13);
            contentPane.add(lblColumna);
            
            textfila = new JTextField();
            textfila.setBounds(169, 87, 96, 19);
            contentPane.add(textfila);
            textfila.setColumns(10);
            
            textColumna = new JTextField();
            textColumna.setColumns(10);
            textColumna.setBounds(169, 124, 96, 19);
            contentPane.add(textColumna);
            
            JTextArea textAreaMatriz = new JTextArea();
            
            textAreaMatriz.setBounds(115, 186, 192, 92);
            contentPane.add(textAreaMatriz);
            
            JButton btnGenerar = new JButton("Generar");
            btnGenerar.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    
                    f1=Integer.parseInt(textfila.getText());
                    c1=Integer.parseInt(textColumna.getText());
                    int mat[][] =new int[f1][c1];
                    generarM(f1, c1, mat);
                    mostrar(f1, c1, mat);

                }
            });
            btnGenerar.setBounds(153, 309, 85, 21);
            contentPane.add(btnGenerar);
            
            JLabel lblNewLabel_1 = new JLabel("Matriz ");
            lblNewLabel_1.setBounds(173, 48, 45, 13);
            contentPane.add(lblNewLabel_1);
        }
    } ```
````

Comment: Hola LastDuck, beinevnido a la comunidad de SO español, te recomiendo que te leas [ask] y te hagas el [tour] para aprender como funciona aqui el preguntar y responder, ya que cuesta entender cual es tu problema. Edita tu pregunta y dejalo lo más claro posible para que se entienda sin problemas.

Answer (score 1):

En este aparatado de tu código estas creando un nuevo objeto `JtexArea` aunque tenga el mismo nombre del objeto `JtexArea` propio de la clase no significa que sean iguales..

```
 JTextArea textAreaMatriz = new JTextArea();
  textAreaMatriz.setBounds(115, 186, 192, 92);
  contentPane.add(textAreaMatriz);
```

para solucionarlo solo inicializa el objeto `JtexArea` de la clase....

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;  
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JTextPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

public class EjemploMatriz extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JTextField textfila;
    private JTextField textColumna;
    private JTextArea textAreaMatriz;
     int mat[][];
    private int f1,c1;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    EjemploMatriz frame = new EjemploMatriz();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public void mostrar(int n,int m, int mat[][]) {
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {
            for(int j=0;j<m;j++) {
            textAreaMatriz.append(Integer.toString(mat[i][j])+" ");
                
            }
            textAreaMatriz.append("\n");
            
        }
    }
    
    public void generarM(int n ,int m,int mat[][]) {
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {
            for(int j=0;j<m;j++) {
                mat[i][j]=(int)(Math.random()*10);
            }
        }
        
    }
    
   
    public EjemploMatriz() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 517, 423);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);
        
        JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("Fila");
        lblNewLabel.setBounds(95, 90, 45, 13);
        contentPane.add(lblNewLabel);
        
        JLabel lblColumna = new JLabel("Columna");
        lblColumna.setBounds(95, 127, 45, 13);
        contentPane.add(lblColumna);
        
        textfila = new JTextField();
        textfila.setBounds(169, 87, 96, 19);
        contentPane.add(textfila);
        textfila.setColumns(10);
        
        textColumna = new JTextField();
        textColumna.setColumns(10);
        textColumna.setBounds(169, 124, 96, 19);
        contentPane.add(textColumna);
        
        textAreaMatriz = new JTextArea();
        
        textAreaMatriz.setBounds(115, 186, 192, 92);
        contentPane.add(textAreaMatriz);
        
        JButton btnGenerar = new JButton("Generar");
        btnGenerar.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                
                f1=Integer.parseInt(textfila.getText());
                c1=Integer.parseInt(textColumna.getText());
                int mat[][] =new int[f1][c1];
                generarM(f1, c1, mat);
                mostrar(f1, c1, mat);

            }
        });
        btnGenerar.setBounds(153, 309, 85, 21);
        contentPane.add(btnGenerar);
        
        JLabel lblNewLabel_1 = new JLabel("Matriz ");
        lblNewLabel_1.setBounds(173, 48, 45, 13);
        contentPane.add(lblNewLabel_1);
    }
}
```

Comment: pero al crear los metodos le inicializo el objeto JtexArea -En el metodo mostra - 
      textAreaMatriz.append(Integer.toString(mat[i][j])+" ");      hay recien lo inicializo y despues lo muestro

Comment: no,en ese método estas haciendo uso de  private JTextArea textAreaMatriz; y en tu constructor EjemploMatriz(); en vez de inicializar ese objeto estas creando e inicializando otro con el mismo nombre